# Burninate [hp] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [hp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp) tag currently has 208 questions. About all of them are tagged with [hp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp) and another tag specifying the related product of HP which is the actual main tag of the respective question.

The [hp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp) tag doesn't provide any additional information in addition to the product-specific tags, it is a meta-tag. In fact, nobody can be a specialist in all the things HP. This is reflected in the question stats for the tag: many are bad or off-topic (or both). Generally, questions using only the [hp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp) tag without any product-specific tag seem to be overwhelmingly off-topic (e.g. they involve using HP laptops or printers).

Generally, people should, can, and do use the actual product-specific tag (which they almost always do already).

Comment: All manufacturer tags are useless. And there are quite a lot of them out there...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Agreed.  Tags for companies are useless to SO.  We do not deal with companies; we work with the programming-related products they produce.

I went ahead and removed the tag from the remaining 200 questions (the other 8 were already done when I started).  The [hp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp) tag will be officially burninated when the tag-cleaning script runs tonight.

Comment: Psst... [its got a tag wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The question you linked says: *"To clarify, this is about tags that have exactly one question"*.  I removed [hp] from *all* questions.

Comment: Ahh, I stand corrected.  Nevermind then.

Comment: I'm not so sure. In the questions I answer, which are mostly OpenGL related, company tags are pretty useful. Something will be tagged [nvidia], [amd] or [intel] depending on which GPU vendor the issue affects.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman agreed; yet `we work with the programming-related products they produce.` - [amd] is more about AMD APIs, chipsets, CPU/GPU instruction sets etc., than about the company branding itself. AMD/nVidia/Intel are, in their way, more of *architectures* than *companies*. HP, at least IMO, ain't.

Comment: Note that SO still has a [tag:pa-risc] with... ahem... 5 question in it. Since it has no wiki tag and many young'uns might have not even heard of it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PA-RISC